# How do I target $0 without getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find the appropriate way to edit an element but it seems like their is only one node with an ID. I have thought of 
my code looks like:

```
var root=document.getElementById("app-mount").childNodes;;
var child = root[n].innerHTML;
```

But this is not reusable to get the path to any element such as `$0` used in chrome dev tools. I was wondering if there was a method one could call on `$0` to just give me the path so one could know how to target it as one does for an ID `document.getElementById('id');`

Edit:
after getting help I have updated my code to look like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('svg')[1].outerHTML="<img id='orb' class='orb' src='https://i.imgur.com/k3d8qMN.gif' width='50' height='60'>"
```

Its for a theme I am making for discord!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I apologise in advanced I don't have much experience writing in forum boards and I am fairly new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I am following your question very well, but if I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

You can use CSS commands to target various HTML elements. eg:

```
document.querySelector('div'); //returns the first div
document.body.querySelectorAll('div'); //returns all the divs attached to the body element
```

You can also target ids:

```
document.querySelector('#app-mount');
```

or classes:

```
document.querySelector('.blue');
```

and query selectors may also be used:

```
document.querySelector('#app-mount > ul > li:nth-child(3)');
```

Comment: Oh this is what jquery is I never realised how useful it is or even really knew what it is. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. This is actually vanilla JavaScript, but it behaves similar to JQuery in the way you can target elements.

Comment: @SeeGreatness as @OwChallie already explained, his answer uses plain Javascript. In jQuery you would use the `.find()` function, which basically is the equivalent to `querySelector`/ `querySelectorAll`